# Use Android Wear device to record hand gestures

Tags: android, android-sensors, gestures, ibmwearables

Is there a way to use the android wear device to send the sensors data to watch and use this data as gesture recognition interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use IBM Mobile Wearables SDK to record and recognise gestures using any Android Wear watch.

You can read about it here: http://wearables.mybluemix.net/

And get it the sdk for free here: https://github.com/ibm-wearables-sdk-for-mobile/ibm-wearables-android-sdk